# A kind/kindly book

Tags: word-usage

I would like to ask if you would use the adjectives "kind" and "kindly" to describe a book or a film? Or are they used to describe people? Is there a better way of describing a book/film that is not at all dark or depressing?

Thank you!

Comment: Your instinct that *kind* is only applied to people is spot-on. Since we can't call a book or film *kind*, you could consider terms like *upbeat*, *happy*, *uplifting*, *bright* (though that doesn't work for books), etc.

Comment: You could say a book has a kind or kindly *tone*

Comment: @user568458, thank you, I like your suggestion, I think it's what I wanted!

Comment: @DanBron - Dan, thank you for pointing out that "kind" is not used with books and films!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for terms to describe a book/film that isn't dark, you can use:

[**light**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/light): [Oxford, sense 11]

> not serious

or [**cheerful**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/cheerful): [Oxford, sense 2]

> giving you a feeling of happiness

You can further expand your options by specifying the **[tone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/tone)** [Oxford, sense 2]

> the general character and attitude of something such as a piece of writing, or the atmosphere of an event
>
> *The general tone of the piece was quite positive.*

Comment: Thank you! I think the tone alternative is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think the terms you are looking for are  ***relaxing* or *pleasant***.

***[Kind](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kind)*** meaning:

> - Agreeable or beneficial: *a dry climate kind to asthmatics*. (AHD)

can be found referring to a book, but it is a quite rare expression:

From: [The book of life:](https://books.google.it/books?id=CbfTjcDmA6gC&pg=PR8&dq=%22a%20kind%20book%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=dDtPVfmyBISqU6TogNgG&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20kind%20book%22&f=false)

> - Finally, ***it is a [kind book](https://books.google.it/books?id=CbfTjcDmA6gC&pg=PR8&dq=%22a%20kind%20book%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=ADpPVbmWKsmAU67wgJAG&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20kind%20book%22&f=false);*** it is not written for its author's glory, nor for his enrichment, but to tell you things that may be useful to you in the brief span of your life. It will attempt to tell you how to live, how to find health and happiness and success, ...

From: [The Australian Journal of Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=h6HyAAAAMAAJ&q=%22a%20kindly%20book%22&dq=%22a%20kindly%20book%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=2DxPVaX5LIGnUIblgdgF&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ):

> - It struck me as a ***[kindly book](https://books.google.it/books?id=h6HyAAAAMAAJ&q=%22a%20kindly%20book%22&dq=%22a%20kindly%20book%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=2DxPVaX5LIGnUIblgdgF&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ)***. The author at all times appears to be patient with the student's slowness of understanding and lack of knowledge, and is careful to ensure that he is always given reasonable assistance with the knottier points.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the meaning "beneficial", now I understand the word kind better! Unfortunately I can't give your comment an up-vote because I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: now I can indeed :)